# Why does CKeditor add line breaks and paragraph before initial text?

Tags: c#, html, ckeditor, paragraph, line-breaks

I have a web page with [a CKEditor on it](http://ckeditor.com/) and my issue is that when I view source or post to the server, I am getting extra spaces and line breaks before the initial text that I type in the textarea.

Here is what I type

[image: Screenshot: editor mode]

and when I click on source, here is what I see:

[image: Screenshot: source mode]

When I post this to the server, before the initial text I see:

```
  <p>\r\n\tWe do deli . . .
```

Does anyone know how I can change the settings so it doesn't add all of this extra paragraph and line breaks when I don't want them.  Is this a setting on CKEditor or is this something that I need to deal with on the client?  I notice that there is also a `</p>` at the end of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a setting, you can disable it. See the docs on [Output Formatting](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting)

Comment: i don't see how to remove the <p> tag.  Also, where would i put this override config code.  Just inside a document ready.  do you have any examples of this in use ?

Answer (score 3):

I Fixed my problem by adding this code n my config.js (just replace `br` for `p`)

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
        ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules('br',
         {
             indent: false,
             breakBeforeOpen: false,
             breakAfterOpen: false,
             breakBeforeClose: false,
             breakAfterClose: false
         });
    });

    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

It applies to all ckeditors avoiding the need of code being replicated ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> )

Answer (score -1):

Its a setting in the enter key plugin code. You can disable it from there and then compile the ckeditor code again...

Comment: are you saying i need to change the source code of ckeditor itself.  Right now i am just referencing the .js file so i am not doing any explicit initialization.

Comment: im just saying see the code of enter key plugin in the src of the ckeditor. thats what puts the br and p tags for enter. i guess there is an option no define the behavior of enter key there....

Comment: Hmm How could I do it? I'm having a similar problem.